# How do I fix my microphone in Garry’s mod and other Source games?

Tags: garrys-mod, voice-chat

When I play on a Garry’s mod server, if I hold the push to talk and icon with my steam profile picture and name appears at the side of the screen showing that my microphone is open and ready to broadcast any sounds it detects. Although, this box does not highlight when my microphone is exposed to sound, therefore my voice is on transmitted to the other players on the server. This has been confirmed though these players telling me in text chat.

I has adjusted all of the setting in the options menu and this does not help. Although, when the test microphone button in the options menu is pressed I can hear my voice if my push to talk button is held. This stops as soon as a disable the testing of my microphone.

I have also tried to user the console command 'voice_loopback_1'. This commands must be entered every time I join a server to allow me to hear my voice. However there is lots of static and it cuts of very quickly. This is unlike the test when the test microphone button is clicked in the options menu, which sounds perfect.

Additionally, my voice chat works well on steam but does not work in other source games such as Dota 2 and Counter Strike.

How can I fix my Garry’s mod microphone?

Comment: Duplicate, maybe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169195/how-do-i-fix-my-mic-in-garrys-mod.

Answer (score 0):

Your microphone must be either your default device or default communication device. Then go into your steam settings and into 'Voice' and auto-detect a device. If that doesn't work, unplugging your microphone and plugging it back in.

Answer (score 0):

If the microphone sounds fine in the test of steam but not in game? I've had a similiar problem. It seems the older source engine games REALLY hate mic boost. So disabling that can help but that might then hinder other applications use of the mic.

What I tend to do is test the mic in steam and see it sounds clear? (Mic at full volume) and then i put the slider down to about 3 quaters rather than full. I have the issue where source engine likes to ramp up my mic too loud and thus creates lots of static and distortion so turning it down might help!

Perhaps the older source engines have built in mic boost as i've noticed alot of peoples mics get ramped up to full volume when a source game is launched.